# Input 'required' attribute still triggers typescript error "type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to refactor from using `useState` to `useRef` when getting text input values in typescript - which I'm reading is the 'righter' way to do when we're not doing any extra manipulation that would require state/rerenders.

So, I've done all that according to the common patterns and it all works except for when I submit the form and run (firebase's) `logInWithEmailAndPassword()` which takes 2 strings parameters - this is triggering the error:

`Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

***Example:***

```js
const emailRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Typescript Error on next line.
  // Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  await logInWithEmailAndPassword(emailRef.current?.value, passwordRef.current?.value);
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      ref={emailRef}
      type="text"
      required
    />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);
```

Now, I (believe that I) understand why this is occurring - because `emailRef.current?.value` could potentially be `undefined` if the input is left empty.

But does typescript not account for the `required` attribute on the input which peforms validation client-side before submitting?

1. The error is specifically related to `logInWithEmailAndPassword()` requiring `string` parameters.
2. Replacing `logInWithEmailAndPassword()` with `console.log()`, which removes the `string` type requirement results in no typescript error.
3. With `console.log()` the `onSubmit` does ***not*** execute if validation fails - I.e. the `input` is empty and `emailRef.current?.value` returns `undefined`.

***So, am I missing something else or is it just that, unfortunately, typescript doesn't deem client-side input validation to be sufficient when type-checking?***

Just to note, I am aware of how I can make this work using e.g. using type assertion, but I'm specifically wondering about the part that client-side input validation plays.

Comment: The problem isn't whether your input is empty, its whether your __ref__ is empty. Notice the question mark: `emailRef.current?.value`.

Comment: ah I see. I was imagining that the optional chaining would prevent execution in the event that the ref is empty/null. But using that ***inside*** of the method would cause failure - is that correct?

Comment: `I was imagining that the optional chaining would prevent execution in the event that the ref is empty/null.` It only prevents `.value` to be accessed and returns `undefined`/`null` immediately.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I was totally aware of that, but my mistake was using it only within the method call as a parameter, instead of as a type guard. So, this works now:
```if (emailRef.current?.value && passwordRef.current?.value) {await logInWithEmailAndPassword(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);}```

Comment: Not that I will use it this way, there is a neater way to do it, but that was my error indeed. Thanks for your help @tkausl much appreciated. Please feel free to post the answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, so thanks so much @tkausl for spotting the error and pointing it out in comments. Will leave this here in case it helps others (or until he posts an answer, which I will mark right).

I'd assumed my use of optional chaining in `emailRef.current?.value` was sufficient as a type guard, but the error was putting it ***inside*** the method call as a parameter, which would be too late and fail when it evaluates to `undefined` or `null` if the ref was empty.

`await logInWithEmailAndPassword(emailRef.current?.value, passwordRef.current?.value);`

Instead the type guard must be performed ***before*** calling the method something like this:

```js
if (emailRef.current?.value && passwordRef.current?.value) {
  await logInWithEmailAndPassword(
    emailRef.current.value,
    passwordRef.current.value,
  );
}
```

The above solution was just to depict the main error, though, which was ***where the optional chaining was used***. I think as a type guard, it beats the purpose of optional chaining (i.e. not having to use an `if/else` statement). So, I'd probably have it end up like this:

```js
const emailRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if(emailRef.current && passwordRef.current) {
    await logInWithEmailAndPassword(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
  }
};

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      ref={emailRef}
      type="text"
      required
    />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);
```